# How properly control execution flow in Python?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

I have a program that operates on a list of images. This program has several steps (i.e. clean image, find object, or many other steps). Some images, can throw an error in some steps.

What I would like to achieve is, depending on the error, be able to log it and skip the image and move on to the next.

What would be the best option? Exceptions? Go To?

UPDATE
I already tried try/except, but I can't figure out the way to skip the object. The problem consists in nested function, so try/except would only treat 1 level, going back to caller, while I have several levels more.
Im not sure if putting try/except.

Comment: Definitely *not* Go To.

Comment: @ScottHunter, yeah. It was just to give an idea of the task. But Im aware that "goto" is frowned upon.

Comment: What have you tried based on your own research, and what were your results? `if:...else:`? `try:...except:`? others? a [mcve] would help us understand how to help you better

Comment: @G.Anderson, tried to elaborate more. Code is too big. I think its more like concept, not the plug&play snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Since we can’t see the code we can’t help you that much, but let me propose a solution.

If you have a list of images and `func_clean_image`, `func_find_object`:

```
import logging
for image in images;
  try:
    func_clean_image(image)
    func_find_object(image)
  except Exception as err:
    logging.warning(f”{err} : {type(err)}”)
```

This way, if a function fails, it will log the message and move to the next image.